# I am reading the text file from java to insert into oracle DB table, how can skip first 2 lines?

Tags: java

I am reading the text file from java to insert into oracle DB table, how can skip first 2 lines?

I want to skip the first 2 lines from text file.

Code :

```
 BufferdReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(/home/test.txt));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bReader.readLine ()) !=null)
    {
 if (line != null)
{
 String[] array = line.split(",",-1) ;
  for (String arrays : array ) {
                System.out.println(arrays );
            }
}
}
```

Comment: How about counting lines and if the counter is still below 2 you just go to the next line instead of handling it? Also note that the `if (line != null)` is superfluous since the while condition already handles this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this before your `while`:

```
int ct = 0;
```

And this before the first `if` on the `while`:

```
if(ct < 2) {
    ct++;
    continue;
}
```